# Interface Builder 3.0 crashes on startup

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I just bought a new Mac and am running Mac OS X 10.6.4 and trying to run Interface Builder 3.2.4 and when I do it consistently crashes with the following error message:

```
Assertion Message: Unimplemented error handling: You don’t have permission to save the file “Library” in the folder “Interface Builder 3.0”.

Thread 0 Asserted:
0   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010011d74b -[IBLibraryController libraryStoragePath] + 419
1   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010011d40c -[IBLibraryController userObjectsStoragePath] + 33
2   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010011c8e8 -[IBLibraryController loadUserAssets] + 41
3   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010011c83d -[IBLibraryController restoreUserPreferences] + 27
4   Interface Builder                0x0000000100002396
5   AppKit                           0x00007fff8000d798 -[NSApplication run] + 80
6   AppKit                           0x00007fff800065f8 NSApplicationMain + 364
7   Interface Builder                0x0000000100001c44
8   Interface Builder                0x0000000000000002
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?  It seems like it would be easy enough to try and modify the permissions of a folder, but I have no clue where to find the folder “Interface Builder 3.0”.

Comment: I'm not at my Mac at the moment, but Interface Builder (and other dev apps) are installed into a root folder on the volume, something like /Development or something like that.  The Library folder may be in an IB subfolder, or it may be a folder inside the IB application bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel dumb now, but hopefully this will help someone along the way.  I found the "Interface Builder 3.0" folder in ~/Library/Application Support.  My user account only had "Read" access so I changed the permissions to "Read & Write".